# Delegating drawing from Renderer to game objects

Tags: java, libgdx, drawing

Currently I'm writing small game on libGDX framework. I have `GameRenderer` class, which has `render()` function, which draws *all* objects in the game. For this goal I need to implement many getters-methods in all game object classes. It's pretty tediously and I'm not sure I'm doing everything right.

So, the question is: is it normal practice to implement `draw()` method in game object classes and then call them from `render()` method of `GameRenderer`? (I'm confused, that they are physical objects and have no connection with drawing)

P.S. I don't use any Scene/Actors.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the [Scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) framework (with `Stages` and `Actors`)? It looks like you can benefit greatly from using it. `Stage` can act as your `GameRenderer` and your `GameObjects` will be `Actors`.

Answer (score 0):

I have always done my game this way. For objects that are special like Player, Enemies, i create a new separate class for them and add a draw/render method in each of these classes. Then i call them from main render loop of the game. Works pretty fine so far.
And for multiple objects you can then easily iterate on arrays too. Like:

```
for(Enemy e:enemyPool)
    e.draw(batch)
```